# ConTeXt: Pixel-perfect figure span across a two-page spread

Tags: context, backgrounds, clip, layers

## Background

Looking to split external figures across two pages, evenly, for a seamless layflat photobook.

## Problem

The seam between two pages is misaligned for illustrations that span two pages. This appears to be due to a thin (~1px) white border that isn't being filled. Here's a zoom showing where the fill does not extend to the edge of the right-hand page:

[image: Unfilled]

This white line would likely show up in the final print, which  I'd like to avoid. The thin line appears at the edge of the left-hand page, as well.

## Code

The code has a ConTeXt part and an SVG part.

### ConTeXt

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
\definepapersize[BookExportSize][
  width=8.5in,
  height=11in,
]

\setuppapersize[BookExportSize]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\setupclipping[nx=2, ny=1]

\setuplayout[
  grid=halfline,
  rightmargin=\zeropoint,
  leftmargin=\zeropoint,
  header=\zeropoint,
  footer=\zeropoint,
  width=\paperwidth,
  height=\paperheight,
  topspace=\zeropoint,
  backspace=\zeropoint,
]

\definelayer[BookIllustrationLayer][
  width=\paperwidth,
  height=\paperheight,
  position=no,
  repeat=no,
]

% A calculation must be run inside a setup (not shown).
\startsetups[BookSetupIllustration]%
\setlayerframed[BookIllustrationLayer][
  frame=off,
  offset=\zeropoint,
  overlay=\zeropoint,
  voffset=.5\paperheight,
]{%
  \ifodd\pagenumber\def\BookClipX{1}\else\def\BookClipX{2}\fi%
  \clip[x=\BookClipX, y=1]{%
    \externalfigure[illustration][
      width=2\paperwidth,
      height=.5\paperheight,
    ]%
  }%
}%
\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds[page][
  setups=BookSetupIllustration,
  background=BookIllustrationLayer,
]

\starttext
Hello \page Hello
\stoptext
```

### Illustration

Save as `illustration.svg` and include it in the same directory as the `.tex` file:

```xml
<svg height="4in" viewBox="0 0 431.8 101.6" width="17in" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2.645833" transform="matrix(.85006833 0 0 .95846476 50.621626 -187.95705)"><path d="m-58.208334 300.77976 503.008004-71.60129"/><path d="m-33.261905 197.42847 480.329435 94.27987"/></g></svg>
```

## Question

How can the clipped background figure be forced to fill the entire page?

If a white border appears on the outside edges (into the bleed area) that's fine because it will be cropped. The issue appears in both Evince and XPDF; I have not tried Acrobat Reader.

### Restrictions

If it is okay to place restrictions on a solution, then, ideally:

- only changes to the setups, layout, or layers;
- without [complex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94439/2148) low-level TeX primitives;
- without [TeX pages](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/startTEXpage);
- without structural changes to the document; and
- without complex [\unprotect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134487/2148) macros (~15 lines or so?).

## Version

```
$ context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.03
mtx-context     | current version: 2019.12.06 19:45
```

## Related

- [ConTeXt: How to span the content across two pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94012/2148)
- [ConTeXt: Expand background image to fill page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134486/2148)
- [ConTeXt: Span background graphics across verso and recto pages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118762/2148)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `\setlayerframed` when you use only a graphic as argument for the layer.

When you need different content for the layer on `odd` and `even` (or `left` and `right`) pages you can use the optional second argument to specify on which page the layer should be placed.

```
\definepapersize
  [BookExportSize]
  [width=8.5in,
   height=11in]

\setuppapersize[BookExportSize]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]

\setuplayout
  [page]
  [grid=halfline]

\setuplayout[page]

\definelayer
  [BookIllustrationLayer]
  [width=\paperwidth,
   height=\paperheight,
   doublesided=yes]

\startsetups[BookSetupIllustration]

    \setlayer
      [BookIllustrationLayer]
      [odd]
      [y=.5\paperheight]
      {\clip[nx=2,x=1]
         {\externalfigure
            [illustration.svg]
            [conversion=mp,
             width=2\paperwidth,
             height=.5\paperheight]}}

    \setlayer
      [BookIllustrationLayer]
      [even]
      [y=.5\paperheight]
      {\clip[nx=2,x=2]
         {\externalfigure
            [illustration.svg]
            [conversion=mp,
             width=2\paperwidth,
             height=.5\paperheight]}}

\stopsetups

\setupbackgrounds
  [page]
  [setups=BookSetupIllustration,
   background=BookIllustrationLayer]

\starttext
Hello \page Hello
\stoptext
```

### Simplified layer setting

Instead of two layers for `even` and `odd` pages you can use a single layer and use the `\doifelseoddpage` command to select the correct `\clip` setting for the current page.

```
\startsetups[BookSetupIllustration]

    \setlayer
      [BookIllustrationLayer]
      [y=.5\paperheight]
      {\doifelseoddpage
         {\clip[nx=2,x=1]}
         {\clip[nx=2,x=2]}%
         {\externalfigure
            [illustration.svg]
            [conversion=mp,
             width=2\paperwidth,
             height=.5\paperheight]}}

\stopsetups
```

In this case when can improve the the page choice even more and move the page selection into the argument of the `\clip` command. The reason why this works is that `\doifelseoddpage` is expandable but this isn't the case for all `\doif` commands, e.g. `\doifelserightpage` isn't expandable and won't work here.

```
\startsetups[BookSetupIllustration]

    \setlayer
      [BookIllustrationLayer]
      [y=.5\paperheight]
      {\clip[nx=2,x=\doifelseoddpage{1}{2}]
         {\externalfigure
            [illustration.svg]
            [conversion=mp,
             width=2\paperwidth,
             height=.5\paperheight]}}

\stopsetups
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused by space being allocated for the frame border. Use `frame=none` instead of `frame=off` to solve the problem, as follows:

```
\setlayerframed[BookIllustrationLayer][
  frame=none,
  offset=\zeropoint,
  overlay=\zeropoint,
  voffset=.5\paperheight,
]
```